# Why is there a buffer overflow in this code?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

As part of a problem, I have a struct which contains `char isGood` and `char filename[32]`

There is a function that checks if a file contains the string `I'm a virus` and return the value in `isGood`.

Then there is the following code:

```
strncpy(currentItem.filename, argv[i], sizeof(currentItem.filename));
if (strlen(argv[i]) > sizeof(currentItem.filename)) {
    currentItem.filename[sizeof(currentItem.filename)] = '\0';
}
```

This code causes an error that a file with a name larger than 32 characters will always return "OK" even when the file contains the string `I'm a virus`.

Why does this happen? Why changing the currentItem.filename changes the value of currentItem.isGood?? It seems to be related to the strncpy because the next question I have to answer says *"What is the proper way of ending a string copied with strncpy?"*

Comment: You need to divide the sizeof with the type of the variable, in your case sizeof(currentItem.filename)/sizeof(char)

Comment: @newboyhun: `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition.

Comment: ohh, yeah sorry, didn't really think about it

Comment: There are three errors in the above fragment. The only line without an error is the line with `}`

Comment: The last statement writes past the end of the buffer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth yes, but why does it change the value stored in currentItem.isGood?

Comment: Because you wrote past the end of the buffer.

Comment: 1) strncpy() is always wrong. 2) the `>` compare is wrong (off by one), the `currentItem.filename[sizeof(currentItem.filename)] = '\0';` is wrong too (off by one)

Comment: @CodingHater: No, it causes *undefined behaviour*.  In this case, you probably just wrote over the storage for `isGood`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth ok, got it. You can write an answer if you want, so I can accept it.

Comment: @newboyhun: `sizeof(currentItem.filename)/sizeof(currentItem.filename[0])` made sense, as it covered the possible use of `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code is your buffer overflow:

```
currentItem.filename[sizeof(currentItem.filename)] = '\0';
```

The value of `sizeof(currentItem.filename)` is the length of the buffer. If you write at that index, you're writing one spot past the end of the array, causing the overflow.

To fix this, write

```
currentItem.filename[sizeof(currentItem.filename) - 1] = '\0';
```

More generally, rather than using `strncpy`, you may want to use `strlcpy`, a compiler extension that most compilers support. It's like `strncpy`, except that it always puts in a null terminator. This means that you never have to worry about adding your own terminator instead.

Hope this helps!